# “The happiest people are those who are too busy to notice whether they are or not.” - What? Happy or Busy?

Tags: quotations

http://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/

> “The happiest people are those who are too busy to notice whether they are or not.”
>   William Feather

I didn't get what are they *too busy to notice* out of the following?

- That they are happy?
- That they are busy?

Comment: It is kind of ambiguous actually. But from the context I would say Your first choice (That they are happy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> “The happiest people are those who are too busy to notice whether they are or not.”

So, your first suggestion seems apt - They are too busy to notice their own happiness.

This means that the happiest people are those individuals who really don't worry too much about their happiness. When you start noticing your happiness, you tend to measure it and we humans are never satisfied with what we have.
 *"I could be happier"* - That is what creeps in when you think about how happy you are. When a person who is too busy to think about it doesn't waste time measuring his happiness. After all, **Ignorance is bliss**.

Answer (score 0):

Often people are sad because they give themselves the time to wonder whether they are happy or not. Making them unhappy. However if you "do your duty" and are too busy to really stop or go for your feelings, you will be happy.